# How to modify the component .xml file with utils:XmlFile using WIX?

Tags: wix

I am trying to create an installer which also installs the xml-file depending on input values, entered in separate dialog. Here

```
</Component>
  <Component Id="ConfigXMLDocument">
    <File Id ="Config" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" Vital ="yes" Source="$(var.Server.ProjectDir)config.xml"/>
    <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <util:PermissionEx User="Users" ChangePermission="yes" GenericAll="yes"/>
    </CreateFolder>

    <util:XmlFile ElementPath ="root/Server/servername" File ="[INSTALLFORDER]config.xml" Sequence="1" Id ="SERVERNAME"
                   Action ="setValue" Value ="THIS VALUE IS NOT BEING SET"  SelectionLanguage="XPath"/>
    <util:XmlFile ElementPath ="root/Server/listenport" File ="[INSTALLFORDER]config.xml" Sequence="2" Id ="PORT"
                 Action ="setValue" Value ="THIS ONE EITHER"/>
  </Component>
```

The problem is that there are no errors and all the paths are resolved correctly, but the installed file remains the same as original. 
If I try to change any other XML-file, It works, but not the one installed.

I found simmilar issues online, but no answers fixed mine.

Is  it possible that XmlFile is just changing file before file is installed? And what else can cause such problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appeared to be not one, but two issues.
The first one was to use FIle ID instead of path, so I replaced this

```
File ="[INSTALLFORDER]config.xml"
```

with this:

```
 File ="[#Config]"
```

But It still didn`t work, during the installation appeared an error that the installer cannot find the file config.xml, so i changed the InstallExecuteSequence to this:

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SchedXmlFile" After="InstallFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

UPD. This still did not work fine. WIX could not open the file with error:
Failed to open XML file path/config.xml, system error: -2147024786

The error appeared to be that wix cannot recognize the BOM in the XML file for some reason:

```
<?xml version"1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

So i just removed it.

Hope this helps.